# Issues with Texlive 2019

Tags: texlive, texlive-2019, update

I stayed on perfectly working earlier versions until now when I decided to give TL 2019 a try. My documents did not compiled, raining thousands of errors on me, and fired up Tlmgr, to update, but I could not.

First of all, Admin maintenance links are gone. Anyhow, I tried both regular user and administrator to start tlmgr, and the result is always the same. I start tlmgr but it looks and acts strange and different. It starts off without a default repository loaded:

[image]

Then I go to the menu and Load default repository. All menus but File are now gone, and File menu does not open.

[image]

When I switch the radio button on the left to Updatable, there is nothing in the list, no matter how long I wait. If I mark some items in the Installed list, Update Marked button still does not become active. Also, Quit button is disabled, and the red X window title button does not work. I have to kill the process to exit.

Now that tlmgr GUI is not working, I issue the following command in the shell:

```
tlmgr update --all
```

It responds with this message:

```
tlmgr.pl: Remote repository is newer than local (2019 < 2020)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

Can anyone explain what is the process for updating TL 2019 installation at the moment?

Comment: If you installed TeXLive 2019 only recently, there will be nothing to update anyway. TeX Live versions get frozen before each new release, meaning no new package versions will be distributed for the older releases.

Comment: why didn't you install TeXLive  2020?

Comment: @Skillmon But why is the UI acting so strangely

Comment: there is no interactive update possible for texlive 2019, you can get a frozen iso image but the ctan/texlive infrastucture does not support updating old releases, as it states in the error text you show at the end.

Comment: @user228785 that I don't know, I never used the GUI version...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I knew someone would ask! Because there is nothing but problems with new software, and the more recent it is, the more problems it creates, the slower it is, and the more time it takes to get anywhere with it. I am minimizing my costs.

Comment: @user228785 not in this case you are trying to do something that can not work.  texlive 2020 is not "new" (the texlive 2021 pretest will be starting soon) and texlive 2019 is archived state and you can not use tlmgr updates with it.

Comment: yes, it can be clearly seen from your question that with texlive 2019 you have no problems at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, in this case. I went back to TL 2018 and it is working fine. I'll stay on it for the time being.

Comment: @user228785 OK fine, but when/if you do update, go straight to texlive 2021 (sometime around easter)

Comment: @user228785 note that you will have exactly the same issue with texlive 2018 as texlive 2019, if you try to use tlmgr you will get the error that the repository is already texlive 2020

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Issues like this make me dread every upgrade since more and more often it introduces extremely time-consuming show-stopper bugs, needless to say performance problems. I just tried the latest TexStudio and it is lagging so much that using it is simply painful, while color highlighting is broken. I would have upgraded happily if quality of software increased with time, but I am seeing the opposite.

Comment: texstudio updates are unrelated to texlive updates so I can't say anything about that (all I know about texstudio is that it is not emacs)  There is nothing you have shown so far that shows texlive 2019 is better or worse than texlive 2018 (it had a lot of improvements actually, as does texlive2020)  all you have shown is that you installed an archived frozen legacy distribution that can not be further updated.

Comment: You know, I have been maintaining latex since 1993, perhaps you think it has been degrading over that time which is fine, but you can't necessarily expect me to agree with you.